# Dynamically modify the list to add new field in each object of the list

Tags: java

I have Student class as follows:-

```
public class Student{
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private String school;

}
```

Now I have list of Students coming from DB -

```
List<Student> students = apiService.getStudents();
```

I want to dynamically modify this list such that it will also contain the combination of id and name as a separate field. So it will be like-

```
public class Student{
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private String school;
   private String idName;
}
```

I can map it like this -

```
        students.stream().map(p -> p.getId() + ","+p.getName())).
        collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

but it will not preserve the original list..

So not sure how to do this.

**Original List -**

```
id= 576, name = "Kevin", school = "ABC"
id= 577, name = "Varon", school = "DEF"
```

**New List -**

```
id= 576, name = "Kevin", school = "ABC", idName= "576Kevin"
id= 577, name = "Varon", school = "DEF", idName= "577Varon"
```

Comment: _contain the combination of id_ Contain it where? Do you have a separate data class?

Comment: "but it will not preserve the original list" - meaning?

I think you can Map and create new Student objects, I can show you the code but need to understand what you meant by this to be certain if that's what you want.

Comment: Contain in the same list as a combination of id and name. This is what I want as a modified list. The original list data is coming from DB.

Comment: that map just converts a list of students to a set of strings

Comment: @MyGod is the field present in the original class? if yes it can be achieved. From DB it'll come null, you can set it in the Map.

Comment: you should have 2 diferent classes one the entity that gets the stuff from db and the other one that convers with the extra things you have or does your student class has the private String idName; but comes null?

Comment: @all I have modified the question with original and required list.

Comment: @RonakJain the field is a combination of the values itself of that row.

Comment: you could do a foreach and use setIdName() and add the things you want i think this is what you are asking?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You cann't have a class with a dynamic number of fields

Comment: @Anon I want to use java8 stream to do that same thing.

Comment: @Eritrean - Field I will add in the Student class itself. Its not dynamic.

Comment: @MyGod stream.forEach() ?

Comment: @MyGod There are two classes in your question - Student with idName and one without. Are they different or do you want to add the field on the fly?

Comment: @RonakJain idName I will add to account for the issue. It will be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using same class

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
static class Student{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String school;
    private String idName; //initially will be null

    public Student(long id, String name, String school) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.school = school;
    }

}
```

Use ForEach

```
list.forEach(student -> student.setIdName(student.id+student.name));
```

Or Streams

```
list.stream().forEach(student -> student.setIdName(student.id+student.name));
```

If you have two separate classes, one with the idName field and one without as in the question.

```
List<Student> list = Stream
        .of(new Student(1, "Sam", "School"),
            new Student(2, "Ronald", "School2"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

 //Create a List with StudentPOJO object having another field as idName
List<StudentPOJO> newList = list
.stream()
.map(student -> new StudentPOJO(student.id, student.name, student.school, student.id + student.name))

.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Classes

Student

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
static class Student{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String school;
}
```

StudentPOJO

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
static class StudentPOJO{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String school;
    private String idName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new list of modified students and add them to the original list like this:

```
List<Student> modifiedStudents = students.stream().map(s -> {
Student modifiedStudent = new Student();
modifiedStudent.setId(s.getId());
modifiedStudent.setName(s.getName());
modifiedStudent.setSchool(s.getSchool());
modifiedStudent.setIdName(s.getId() + "," + s.getName());
return modifiedStudent;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
students.addAll(modifiedStudents);
```

This will preserve the original list and also add the modified students to it.

Comment: The question was "how to add new a new field to a class" not "how add new element to a list"